# Dynamically terminate Observable based on another observable | RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I have array of Observables, say `[Observable <WriteTaskResult>]`

I want to perform all write tasks keeping their order, and if any one of them fails then I want to perform `Observable<ResetTaskResult>`

Following function will return observable of type `BatchTasksResult` for tracking tasks progress.

Sample Code:

```
enum BatchTasksResult{
    case elapsedTime(Double)
    case failedFatal
    case rolledback
    case success
}

func writeBlocks(tasks: [WriteTask]) -> Observable<BatchTasksResult>{
    return Observable.create {(observable) -> Disposable in
       let allTasks: [Observable<WriteTaskResult>] = self.writeSomewhere(tasks)
       Observable.concat(allTasks)
         .subscribe { writeTaskResult in
               observable.onNext(.elapsedTime(writeTaskResult.totalTime))
            } 
            onError: { (err) in
               // Perform Observable<ResetTaskResult>
               // if ResetTask was successful then observable.onNext(.rolledback)
               // if ResetTask failed then observable.onNext(.failedFatal)
            }
            onCompleted: {
               observable.onNext(.success)
            }
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
       return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

How do I trigger rollback logic using Observable from onError of allTasks' observable?

Simple solution seems nested observable, but that's not good practice, I guess? I tried FlatMap, but it can't really solve *"If any sinlge task fails, then rollback and reset"* Any other solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to add the extra level of indirection with the `create` function. Every Observable operator already creates a new object.

And when you *do* use `Observable.create`, **do not** dispose in an external dispose bag and return a `Disposables.create()`. Just return the disposable that you just created.

Here's the appropriate way to do what you want:

```
func writeBlocks(tasks: [WriteTask], resetTask: Single<ResetTaskResult>) -> Observable<BatchTasksResult> {
    // create the array of write tasks and concat them. You seem to have that down.
    let result = Observable.concat(tasks.map(writeSomewhere(task:)).map { $0.asObservable() })
        .share() // the share is needed because you are using the value twice below.
    return Observable.merge(
        // push out the elapsed time for each task.
        result.map { BatchTasksResult.elapsedTime($0.totalTime) },
        // when the last one is done, push out the success event.
        result.takeLast(1).map { _ in BatchTasksResult.success }
    )
    .catch { _ in
        resetTask // the resetTask will get subscribed to if needed.
            .map { _ in BatchTasksResult.rolledback } // if successful emit a rollback
            .catch { _ in Single.just(BatchTasksResult.failedFatal) } // otherwise emit the failure.
            .asObservable()
    }
}

func writeSomewhere(task: WriteTask) -> Single<WriteTaskResult> {
    // create a Single that performs the write and emits a result.
}
```

Comment: This helped me.  Thanks.
But I have one doubt, .catch/.catchError will still allow further sequence to be executed right? If one were to avoid that they should use .do(onError:) right?

Comment: Once the `concat` emits an error, it will stop. No more task writes will occur. That will happen even if something later catches the error.

Comment: Wait let me explain in different comment.

Comment: Then I don't understand your doubt. The `resetTask` is (presumably) a Single. So once it emits (or errors) it will stop. There's no "further sequence" to execute at that point...

Comment: Yeah, I get that but my doubt was different. Suppose Observable.concat().shared() and the 1 observable is used for error handling only using .catch(), and 2nd seperate observable is used as an onComplete equivalent using .takeLast(1). Then suppose these both 1 and 2 are merged. Now anything that subscribes this will be getting two events in case there is no error. As .catch() will be ignored and source observable is triggered. To avoid that, and stop flow at catch itself  in case of noerror we have to used something like .skipWhile(), add predicate to check if it's catch's observable or source

Comment: I know this is already to use case specific. But thanks for the time. This answer helped me simplify my code a lot. Cheers!

Comment: On no error. The first line of the merge emits a value every time a write completes. The second line of the merge emits a value once all the writes are complete. Anything that subscribes to this will be getting one event for each write and one event when all the writes are finished. I thought that's what you wanted.

Comment: Yeah, that's what expected for OG question. But my actual problem bit more complex than mentioned here. It's like 'Send all data, and if any single fails, then reschedule remaining for next time'. Where owner will only order 'Send All' and won't have to worry if it failed or not, as it will eventually be successed sometime later.